# Добрый день, при добавлении новой категории на Wordpress не добавляет?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

при добавлении новой категории на Wordpress не добавляет, не работает также добавление нового бренда и плагин WOOCS - WooCommerce Currency Switcher не добавляет Add Currency, не подскажите в чём может быть проблема?
Сайт находится на хостинге.

Comment: Пробовали отключить все установленные плагины?

Answer (score 0):

Вся проблема была в плагине qTranslate-X